# Combine multiple vue.js apps dynamically in another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe

Is it possible to do something like this:

i currently have 2 VUE.js apps. They are independently deployed.
They all use Keycloak for authentication.

Now i want to have a 3rd app, which combines the UIs or maybe even parts of the UIs of the other 2 apps in its UI at runtime. Just a bit like in [Microfrontends](https://micro-frontends.org/) but with VUE.js.

Normally you would think of using an iframe for this. But iframes have some disadvantages (security, usability, ...)

Isn't there a more "integrated" way in loading html (including its css and js) from another location, assuming its from the same domain or subdomain and using the same Keycloak for authentication?

Comment: The question isn't specific enough for SO. Probably try softwareengineering.stackexchange.com . But any way, it's unclear what is the problem here. You can have several Vue apps per page, e.g. like widgets. It's unnecessary to wrap them with iframe on your own domain (no cors issues), as long as the layout doesn't cause problems.

Comment: @Estus Flask The thing is: the two existing apps are deployed independant. The also run standalone. And yes, i think too that it is unnecessary to wrap them with iframe. That's why i asked how. How to use several already deployed Vue apps per page from different locations in another vue app?

Comment: I reread the question and seem to see what you mean. You can mount nested apps inside host app and communicate with them through their Vue instances. If these apps rely on external assets they need to be loaded beforehand. I don't think it's efficient because you'll have several Vue, etc lib versions loaded while you could have only one. The concept of micro frontends comes with a price. Unless you have problems with different dep versions between apps, it's much more practical to import components from other apps and have only one app instance.

Comment: Have a look at single-spa https://single-spa.js.org/